# Eloquent Relationship Laravel 5.4

Tags: eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.4

I have three tables as follows `users`, `jobs` and `job_statuses` with the following simple schema.

```
**Users Table** 
id, user_id, email, password

**Jobs Table** 
id, user_id, title, description, status_id

**Job_statuses Table**
id, status
```

I have successfully retrieved a list of `Jobs` posted by an `authorized user` using a `one-to-many relationship` but I can't get hold on the `status` using the `status_id`

**User Model**

```
public function job(){
    return $this->hasMany(Job::class, 'user_id')->take(5);
}
```

**Job Model**

```
 public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function jabstatus() {
    return $this->hasOne(JabStatus::class, 'status_id', 'id');
}
```

**Job_Statuses Model**

```
public function statuses() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Job::class, 'id', 'status_id');
}
```

When try doing something like:

```
@foreach($user->job as $job)
    {{$job->statuses->status}}
@endforeach
```

I get an error from this: `{{$job->statuses->status}}`

A well explained answer will do, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to get what I wanted.

What I had was a multiple eloquent relationship.

**Job Model**

```
public function jobstatus() {
    return $this->hasOne(JobStatus::class, 'id');
}
```

**JobStatus Model**

```
  public function status() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Job::class);
}
```

Then:

```
$user = User::with(['profile', 'review', 'job.jobstatus'])->find(Auth::User()->user_id);

    return view('user.dashboard', ['user' => $user]);
```

Then on my View:

```
@foreach(@$user->job as $job)
 {{$jab->jobstatus->status}}
@endforeach
```